# Meaning of поехавшие (люди)

Tags: значения, словоупотребление, сленг

In a comment about using foul language:

> Только я почти никогда его не использую. Разве что против особо ''поехавших'' в качестве тяжелой артиллерии :D

*I almost never use it. Except against especially ___ people, by way of heavy artillery.*

I can't find a meaning for **поехавший** in any dictionary, so I reckon it must be very colloquial or a funny made-up word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Поехавший` means "crazy, weird, inadequate" here. There is a colloquial idiom `[у него] крыша поехала` (literary "[his] roof is gone") which means "he is off his chump (crumpet, noggin, nut, rocker, trolley); he has bats in his belfry; he has gone bughouse (bugs)", so the verb `поехать` can also mean "go crazy", and `поехавший` is the past active participle from this verb.

> Он ещё хотел что-то сказать, но так и остался с открытым ртом, чем-то неожиданно напуганный. - Ты чё? - уставился на него Вовка. - Крыша поехала? (Б. Новосельцев, Отработка)
>
> He wanted to say a few words more, but suddenly turned to stone, his mouth agape. 'What's the matter with you?' Vovka stared at him. 'Have you gone off your rocker, or what?'

Comment: Got it! She only uses bad language against certain "wackos"! It makes perfect sense, thank you - and GREAT example :)

Comment: Also, is it пое́ хавший или поеха́ вший?

Comment: @CocoPop - Поéхавший.

Answer (score -1):

Только я почти никогда его не использую. Разве что против особо ''поехавших'' в качестве тяжелой артиллерии :D
I almost never use it. Except against especially *_* people, by way of heavy artillery.

I almost never use it. Except against people that are naturally have gone far (crazy), in the way that i use heavy artillery.

Comment: Except against complete nutjobs by way of heavy artillery.

Comment: I downvote this because you post translations with errors (although minor but still misleading). Besides I can't understand the meaning of the signs _ - placeholder for the right word? and () - optional addition or alternative? 'I' should be a capital letter.